# Wrong R data type or bad data?

Tags: r, numbers, integer

I'm having trouble doing simple functions on a data frame and am unsure whether it's the data type of the column, or bad data in the data frame.

I exported a SQL query into a CSV file, then loaded it into a data frame, then attached it.

```
df <-read.csv("~/Desktop/orders.csv")
Attach(df)
```

When I am done, and run `str(df)`, here is what I get:

```
$ AccountID: Factor w/ 18093 levels "(819947 row(s) affected)",..: 10 97 167 207 207 299 299 309 352 573 ...
$ OrderID   : int  1874197767 1874197860 1874196789 1874206918 1874209100 1874207018 1874209111 1874233050 1874196791 1875081598 ...
$ OrderDate : Factor w/ 280 levels "","2010-09-24",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ NumofProducts  : int  16 6 4 6 10 4 2 4 6 40 ...
$ OrderTotal    : num  20.3 13.8 12.5 13.8 16.4 ...
$ SpecialOrder : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Trying to run the following functions, here is what I get:

```
> length(OrderID)
[1] 0

> min(OrderTotal)
[1] NA

> min(OrderTotal, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5.00

> mean(NumofProducts)
[1] NA

> mean(NumofProducts, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 3.462902
```

I have two questions related to this data frame:

- Do I have the right data types for the columns?  Nums versus integers versus decimals.
- Is there a way to review the data set to find the rows that are driving the need to use na.rm=TRUE to make the function work?  I'd like to know how many there are, etc.

Comment: The usual function to expose column names to the global environment is attach(df), so are you using a different function or did you misspell it?

Comment: @DWin Do you mean `attach()` versus `Attach()`?

Comment: Yes. in R Attach() is not a base function. So if it works it must come from some other package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between num and int is pretty irrelevant at this stage.

See help(is.na) for starters on NA handling. Do things like:

```
sum(is.na(foo))
```

to see how many foo's are NA values. Then things like:

```
df[is.na(df$foo),]
```

to see the rows of df where foo is NA.